# Simplifying complex statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, subquery, case, sql-server-2014

So this query below is returning duplicate values for numbers 1 and 39. Is there a way to rewrite this query so that we can ignore the value 1 if 30 or 39 is present.

```
SELECT       A.UserId,
             U.transformerID , 
             U.productID as ProductID,
             A.Name,
             A.Number,

            (CASE A.Number WHEN 39 THEN 'MEP' WHEN 30 THEN ' Disconnect' 
            ELSE (SELECT (CASE WHEN x.ProductMSP < 0.35  AND datediff(d,x.InsertTime, GETDATE()) < 10 THEN 'MSP' ELSE 'End of Life' END ) as cycle
            FROM Product x where x.ProductSerialNo = u.ProductID and x.UserId = a.UserId) END),
            (select datediff(d,InsertionDateTime, GETDATE()) from Product where productserialno = u.ProductID and userid = A.UserId and datediff(d,InsertTime, GETDATE()) > 60 ),
            (select x.InsertionDateTime from product x where x.productserialno = u.ProductID and x.userid = A.UserId) as InsertDate,
            max(A.DateTime) Date
FROM         [User] U ,
             MMA A,
             product p,
             HealthLinksData h

WHERE A.UserId = U.UserID
AND p.UserId = u.UserID
AND A.Number in (1,30,39)
AND LEN(u.TransformerID ) > 0
AND LEN(u.ProductID) > 0
AND datediff(d,s.InsertTime, GETDATE()) > 20
AND u.ProductID != 7679
AND CONVERT(INT, u.productID) = CONVERT(INT, h.Serial_Batchnumber)
and  SerialNo in (1650,
1918, 1925, 1160, 1919, 1941, 1927, 1195, 1131, 1175, 1985, 1949, 1919, 
1910, 1939, 1212, 1239, 1917, 1919, 1986, 1993, 1926, 1926, 1285, 1268, 
1971,)  
GROUP BY A.UserId, U.TransformerID, u.SensorID, A.Number, A.Name 
ORDER BY max(A.DateTime) desc
```

Comment: I don't think the word "simplify" means what you think it means in this context, but you can use a `NOT EXISTS()` function in conjunction with your filter on `AlertNumber` to do what you want.

Comment: You really should start using ANSI-92 style joins. They have been around now for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins

Comment: Not sure why you have all those subqueries in here. Why not just reference the Product table for each of those? The product table is already in your query.

Comment: @seanlange, Perhaps i should have prefaced my request by citing that i did not write this query but was given to adjust, hence why i posted it here strictly for some aid and tsql query contribution. I acknowledge it's an old join style but i'm just asking for suggestions and tip to simplify the query.

Comment: @tabAlleman, do you mind showing an example or indicate where to put that in the query. I'm not that familiar with that operator.

Comment: It doesn't matter who wrote it, it should be fixed. Fix the join syntax and get rid of the redundant subqueries. And not sure what you mean by "simplify". I am guessing you have something in particular in there you want to change.

Comment: @seanlange, it should be fixed, got it, i'll make a note of that. Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: OK so you don't want my opinion, whatever. I am willing to help you but still don't know what it is you want to do.

Comment: @seanlange, i'm confused. I posed a question here seeking help and you kindly responded (much appreciated) by criticizing the sql join style which i can understand to some extent but that's all you did even after explaining i was given the query as is. So i'll try again, If the query is ran as is, i get duplicate numbers for 1 and 39 values (pay attention to the a.number in the where clause).  I am trying to find out if there's a way to avoid the duplicate results by rewriting the query to ignore the value 1 if 39 or 30 is present.

Comment: At least we are getting somewhere now. You talked about wanting to simplify it which nobody was understanding. But the real issue is that it doesn't return the correct data. If I interpret this correctly you could have the value 1 or 39 or 30 in the Number column? And you want only 1 row to be returned, preferably with the greatest value in that column? FWIW, those are not duplicates as the values are different. What if you simply change A.Number to MAX(A.Number) and remove that column from the group by? And my point all along is to fix the other stuff since you are already in here. :)

Comment: The best thing you can do for this or any question is to post table definitions and sample data in a consumable format. Here is an excellent article on that topic. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Sorry I'm late to the party. Dealing with duplicated, or partially duplicated, rows always means digging into the actual data. It's seldom something that can be diagnosed with any accuracy just by looking at the query. That's especially true with a complex query. If you can include some sample data that generates what you're currently getting, and also a sample of what you would like to get, it would go a long way towards our ability to help you troubleshoot. The article Sean linked to has great samples and some useful tools to help you.

Comment: @DBANewbie What do you want to achieve???  Where's sample input???  Where's expected output???  Where's table structure???  Don't just dump your broken query, and expect everybody knows what your data look like. 
 Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Where does the alias `s` come from in this part of the `where`: `datediff(d,s.InsertTime, GETDATE()) > 20`  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have just duplicated your query, first query is 30,39, and the second is 1, that has an explicit check for not exist like the first comment explained (disclaimer: not tested)

```
SELECT       A.UserId,
         U.transformerID , 
         U.productID as ProductID,
         A.Name,
         A.Number,

        (CASE A.Number WHEN 39 THEN 'MEP' WHEN 30 THEN ' Disconnect' 
        ELSE (SELECT (CASE WHEN x.ProductMSP < 0.35  AND datediff(d,x.InsertTime, GETDATE()) < 10 THEN 'MSP' ELSE 'End of Life' END ) as cycle
        FROM Product x where x.ProductSerialNo = u.ProductID and x.UserId = a.UserId) END),
        (select datediff(d,InsertionDateTime, GETDATE()) from Product where productserialno = u.ProductID and userid = A.UserId and datediff(d,InsertTime, GETDATE()) > 60 ),
        (select x.InsertionDateTime from product x where x.productserialno = u.ProductID and x.userid = A.UserId) as InsertDate,
        max(A.DateTime) Date
FROM         [User] U ,
         MMA A,
         product p,
         HealthLinksData h

WHERE A.UserId = U.UserID
AND p.UserId = u.UserID
AND A.Number in (30,39)
AND LEN(u.TransformerID ) > 0
AND LEN(u.ProductID) > 0
AND datediff(d,s.InsertTime, GETDATE()) > 20
AND u.ProductID != 7679
AND CONVERT(INT, u.productID) = CONVERT(INT, h.Serial_Batchnumber)
and  SerialNo in (1650,
1918, 1925, 1160, 1919, 1941, 1927, 1195, 1131, 1175, 1985, 1949, 
1919, 
1910, 1939, 1212, 1239, 1917, 1919, 1986, 1993, 1926, 1926, 1285, 1268, 
1971,)  
GROUP BY A.UserId, U.TransformerID, u.SensorID, A.Number, A.Name 
ORDER BY max(A.DateTime) desc

union

SELECT       A.UserId,
         U.transformerID , 
         U.productID as ProductID,
         A.Name,
         A.Number,

        (CASE A.Number WHEN 39 THEN 'MEP' WHEN 30 THEN ' Disconnect' 
        ELSE (SELECT (CASE WHEN x.ProductMSP < 0.35  AND datediff(d,x.InsertTime, GETDATE()) < 10 THEN 'MSP' ELSE 'End of Life' END ) as cycle
        FROM Product x where x.ProductSerialNo = u.ProductID and x.UserId = a.UserId) END),
        (select datediff(d,InsertionDateTime, GETDATE()) from Product where productserialno = u.ProductID and userid = A.UserId and datediff(d,InsertTime, GETDATE()) > 60 ),
        (select x.InsertionDateTime from product x where x.productserialno = u.ProductID and x.userid = A.UserId) as InsertDate,
        max(A.DateTime) Date
FROM         [User] U ,
         MMA A,
         product p,
         HealthLinksData h

WHERE A.UserId = U.UserID
AND p.UserId = u.UserID
AND A.Number in (1) and not exist(select * from MMA A2 where A2.UserId = A.UserId and A2.Number in (30,39)
AND LEN(u.TransformerID ) > 0
AND LEN(u.ProductID) > 0
AND datediff(d,s.InsertTime, GETDATE()) > 20
AND u.ProductID != 7679
AND CONVERT(INT, u.productID) = CONVERT(INT, h.Serial_Batchnumber)
and  SerialNo in (1650,
1918, 1925, 1160, 1919, 1941, 1927, 1195, 1131, 1175, 1985, 1949, 1919, 
1910, 1939, 1212, 1239, 1917, 1919, 1986, 1993, 1926, 1926, 1285, 1268, 
1971,)  
GROUP BY A.UserId, U.TransformerID, u.SensorID, A.Number, A.Name 
ORDER BY max(A.DateTime) desc
```